COLMAP and CUDA installed, no dense reconstruction possible
I just tried COLMAP yesterday, and it works... but I only get point clouds, but never a dense reconstruction (aka 3D object).
Typing nvcc --version confirms that CUDA is installed:
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Jan__6_16:45:21_PST_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.0, V12.0.140
Build cuda_12.0.r12.0/compiler.32267302_0

I also did reboots after installing packages, but nothing works.
GPU:
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU116M [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] TU116M [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 160
    Memory at a0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 6000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at 6010000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at a1080000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [250] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [258] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [420] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
    Capabilities: [900] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [bb0] Physical Resizable BAR
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia

I still haven't found any solution for my problem. It never creates a dense reconstruction .ply file.
Trying the "Dense Reconstruction" menu ends with the error Dense stereo reconstruction requires CUDA, which is not available on your system.
